# Trying to calculate percent times fish/chicken/meat were eaten out of total (14) meals and display it. It populates the array with all 0's

Tags: java

After calculating the number of times the people in the array ate (Fish, Chicken, Meat) I then need to calculate the percentage of times they ate that selection and display it. When I attempt it in the 'fillArray' method the results are all populating as 0. What am I doing wrong/how can I correct it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SortArrayHomework{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


          int[] fish = new int[10];
          int[] chicken = new int[10];
          int[] meat = new int[10];

          String[] names = new String[10];

          File fn = new File("foodtracking.txt");
          Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fn);

          int mp = 0;

            fillArray(inputFile,names,fish,chicken,meat,mp);


            sortArraynames(names,fish,chicken,meat,mp);

            displayArray(names,fish,chicken,meat,mp);



    } // end main

//=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
public static void sortArraynames(String[] n,int[] f, int[] c, int[] m,int mp){

    String temp;
    int stemp;
    int stemp1;
    int stemp2;

    for(int indx = 0; indx<n.length; indx++)            //current low position
        for(int indx1=indx+1; indx1<n.length; indx1++)  // current position in the array I am comparing to
            if(n[indx].compareToIgnoreCase(n[indx1]) > 0){
                temp = n[indx];                     //swp the two values
                n[indx] = n[indx1];
                n[indx1] = temp;

                stemp = f[indx];                        //swp the two values
                f[indx] = f[indx1];
                f[indx1] = stemp;

                stemp1 = c[indx];                       //swp the two values
                c[indx] = c[indx1];
                c[indx1] = stemp1;

                stemp2 = m[indx];                       //swp the two values
                m[indx] = m[indx1];
                m[indx1] = stemp2;}
    }//end sortArray method
//=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

public static void fillArray(Scanner fileIn,String[] names,  int[] fish, int[] chicken, int[] meat, int mp){

    int total;

    for(int indx = 0; indx < names.length; indx++){
    names[indx] = fileIn.nextLine();
    if(names[indx].length() == 0)names[indx] = fileIn.nextLine();
    fish[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
    chicken[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
    meat[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
    total = ((fish[indx] + chicken[indx]) + meat[indx]);
    mp = (meat[indx] / total)*100;}
    return;

}//end fillArray method

//=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//n is the name array
//f is the fish array
//c is the chicken array
//m is the meat array
public static void displayArray(String[] n,int[] f, int[] c, int[] m,int mp){


    System.out.printf("%18s  %4s      %7s  %4s %10s  %10s  %10s\n","     Name     ","Fish","Chicken","Meat","% Fish","% Chicken","% Meat");
    System.out.printf("%18s  %4s   %7s  %4s %10s  %10s  %10s\n","--------------","-------","-------","----","------","---------","------");

    for(int indx = 0; indx < n.length; indx++) System.out.printf("%-18s    %-2d         %-2d    %-2d  %-2d\n",n[indx],f[indx],c[indx],m[indx],mp);


    return;



}//end displayArray method

} // end class
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the variable `mp`. Which I am guessing is the value you are trying to print? Put a `System.out.println(mp);` in the for loop (under the `mp` initialization) to verify that it is working as intended

Comment: That doesn't work

 for(int indx = 0; indx < n.length; indx++) System.out.printf("%-18s    %-2d         %-2d    %-2d  %-2d\n",n[indx],f[indx],c[indx],m[indx],mp);


And it's being called here to display, all 0s

Comment: The problem is you are trying to pass an integer as a reference, but integers are only pass by value.

Comment: One thing that might have been a problem in fillArray() is the second-to-last line: 'mp = (meat[indx] / total)*100;' This would have always evaluated to zero because of integer division. The reason that it isn't a problem has been pointed out by others.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not pass by reference it is pass by value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SortArrayHomework{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        int[] fish = new int[10];
        int[] chicken = new int[10];
        int[] meat = new int[10];

        String[] names = new String[10];

        File fn = new File("foodtracking.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fn);

        int[] mp = new int[10];

        fillArray(inputFile,names,fish,chicken,meat,mp);


        sortArraynames(names,fish,chicken,meat);

        displayArray(names,fish,chicken,meat,mp);



    } // end main

    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    public static void sortArraynames(String[] n, int[] f, int[] c, int[] m){

        String temp;
        int stemp;
        int stemp1;
        int stemp2;

        for(int indx = 0; indx<n.length; indx++)            //current low position
            for(int indx1=indx+1; indx1<n.length; indx1++)  // current position in the array I am comparing to
                if(n[indx].compareToIgnoreCase(n[indx1]) > 0){
                    temp = n[indx];                     //swp the two values
                    n[indx] = n[indx1];
                    n[indx1] = temp;

                    stemp = f[indx];                        //swp the two values
                    f[indx] = f[indx1];
                    f[indx1] = stemp;

                    stemp1 = c[indx];                       //swp the two values
                    c[indx] = c[indx1];
                    c[indx1] = stemp1;

                    stemp2 = m[indx];                       //swp the two values
                    m[indx] = m[indx1];
                    m[indx1] = stemp2;}
    }//end sortArray method
//=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

    public static void fillArray(Scanner fileIn,String[] names,  int[] fish, int[] chicken, int[] meat, int[] mp){

        int total;

        for(int indx = 0; indx < names.length; indx++){
            names[indx] = fileIn.nextLine();
            if(names[indx].length() == 0)names[indx] = fileIn.nextLine();
            fish[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
            chicken[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
            meat[indx] = fileIn.nextInt();
            total = ((fish[indx] + chicken[indx]) + meat[indx]);
            mp[indx] = (int) (((double) meat[indx] / total) * 100d);
        }
        return;

    }//end fillArray method

    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//n is the name array
//f is the fish array
//c is the chicken array
//m is the meat array
    public static void displayArray(String[] n,int[] f, int[] c, int[] m,int[] mp){


        System.out.printf("%18s  %4s      %7s  %4s %10s  %10s  %10s\n","     Name     ","Fish","Chicken","Meat","% Fish","% Chicken","% Meat");
        System.out.printf("%18s  %4s   %7s  %4s %10s  %10s  %10s\n","--------------","-------","-------","----","------","---------","------");

        for(int indx = 0; indx < n.length; indx++) System.out.printf("%-18s    %-2d         %-2d    %-2d  %-2d\n",n[indx],f[indx],c[indx],m[indx],mp[indx]);


        return;



    }//end displayArray method

} // end class
```

Comment: still displays as all 0s

Comment: John Murphy
8 3 3
Katherine Cleary
9 1 4
Isaac Fajerman
2 8 4
Marsha Smiith
8 3 4
Jason Meier
9 1 4
Inna Johnson
2 2 10
Walter Philips
5 4 5
Tracey Cannon
1 3 10
Sheryl Rothman
4 5 5
Jeff Gottlieb
5 6 3

Comment: You will find that `3/14` is `0.21` which as an integer is `0`. Convert mp to a `double` or a `float`.

Comment: Also, when doing the percent calculation cast the integers to a double or a float. `mp[indx] = ((double) meat[indx] / (double) total) * 100d;`

Comment: it doesn't apply the * 100 to the 0.21 first?

Comment: No, since both values inside the braces are integers. It will convert the division into an integer and then multiply the 100. Try this out: `int test = (3 / 14) * 100;
        System.out.println(test);

        int test2 = (int) (((double) 3 / 14) * 100d);
        System.out.println(test2);`

Comment: Therefore, you could do this instead of converting it `mp[indx] = (int) (((double) meat[indx] / total) * 100d);`